# error loading gazebo_plugins models (Pioneer)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get one weird error trying to load some of the samples/models provided in gazebo_plugins on Ubuntu 16.04 with ROS kinetic installed via official repositories.

Particularly, for the multi_robot_scenario fails. On the other hand the tricycle demo or the pendulum demos work properly.

This is the error I get trying to load the multi_robot_scenario demo.

```
Error [Param.cc:451] Unable to set value [-nan -nan -nan] for key[size]
gzserver: /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreNode.cpp:630: virtual void Ogre::Node::setScale(const Ogre::Vector3&): Assertion `!inScale.isNaN() && "Invalid vector supplied as parameter"' failed.
[r1/urdf_spawner-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/geus/.ros/log/37a5e414-7527-11e6-8e8a-d8cb8abfd844/r1-urdf_spawner-4*.log
Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
Aborted (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 19670, exit code 134, cmd /media/geus/Storage/simulation_gazebo/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/scripts/gzserver -e ode worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/geus/.ros/log/37a5e414-7527-11e6-8e8a-d8cb8abfd844/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/geus/.ros/log/37a5e414-7527-11e6-8e8a-d8cb8abfd844/gazebo-2*.log
```

In order to reproduce this issue you have to install the package ros-kinetic-gazebo-plugins and execute the launch file:

> roslaunch $(rospack find gazebo_plugins)/test/multi_robot_scenario/launch/multi_robot_scenario.launch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243283/error-loading-gazebo_plugins-models-(pioneer)/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2016-09-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally found the solution.

It looks like there is a bug in gazebo 7.0.0 contained in the kinetic debian package repository for ubuntu 16.04. The bug appears when the urdf descriptions contains collision geometry objects with zero value parameters.

For instance in "gazebo_plugins/test/multi_robot_scenario/xacro/p3dx/pioneer3dx_wheel.xacro":
we find this chunk of urdf:

```
<collision>
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <geometry>
    <box size="0 0 0"/>
  </geometry>
</collision>
```

The box size must not be zero. The error is solved if the above code chunk is replaced by the code chunk below:

```
<collision>
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <geometry>
    <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
  </geometry>
</collision>
```

It is needed to apply this correction in several place in order to make work this demo:

> roslaunch $(rospack find gazebo_plugins)/test/multi_robot_scenario/launch/multi_robot_scenario.launch

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-09**:
Hm. Is this a regression in Gazebo 7? In any case, it would be really nice if you could report this to the Gazebo bug tracker or the `gazebo_plugins` tracker. Even if `0 0 0` is not a legal value, Gazebo should not just crash, imo.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2016-09-09**:
https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/488

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-08**:
@Pablo-Iñigo-Blasco, what files did you need to change (if you can still remember)? I changed the battery_block, sonar, swivel, sonar, and wheel xacro files and it still didn't fix the issue. I'm wondering if I missed one.